# How to get the likes of every tweet containing a specific hashtag with tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I can retrieve tweets with a specific hashtag using tweepy:

Code:

```
from os import access
import tweepy 
import configparser
import pandas as pd

# config = configparser.ConfigParser()
# config.read('config.ini')

api_key = ''
api_key_secret = ''

access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_key_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

# user = '@veritasium'
keywords = '#SheHulk'
limit = 1200

tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q = keywords, count = 100, tweet_mode =     'extended').items(limit)


columns = ['User', 'Tweet']
data = []

for tweet in tweets:
    data.append([tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.full_text])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

What I want to know is that if I can get the number of likes with every tweet that is retrieved. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Twitter API V1.1 (see documentation [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet)), that field was called `favorite_count`.

```
for tweet in tweets:
    print(f"That tweet has {tweet.favorite_count} likes").
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried favorite_xount but it does not give me the accurate number of likes, for e.g, one tweet had 6 likes but it was giving me 0 likes.

Comment: @FakhrAli Can you share the link to the tweet you're talking about?

Comment: https://twitter.com/neiltyson/status/1560842148119023617?t=QfoyuLHaoMF8oD0YIX-1tg&s=19                It's not an isolated issue, there are inconsistencies in the like count when retrieving multiple tweets. Don't understand why.